# Why my SCO does not count as finished

Tags: javascript, api, scorm, scorm2004

I have very simple SCO, containing empty html page. Using chrome dev tools I use pipwerks scorm api wrapper to initialize LMS connection, set cmi.completion_status to "completed" and cmi.success_status to "failed" (according to [scorm runtime reference](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/) ), save and exit. When I return back to LMS web page my attempt is not considered "completed". If I try and set success status to "passed" everything is good, SCO is considered completed and I'm able to close it. I guess it's some imsmanifest.xml option I'm missing to get this done.

This is my imsmanifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<manifest identifier="com.scorm.golfsamples.contentpackaging.singlesco.20043rd" version="1"
          xmlns="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:adlcp="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3"
          xmlns:adlseq="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3"
          xmlns:adlnav="http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3"
          xmlns:imsss="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imscp_v1p1 imscp_v1p1.xsd
                              http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlcp_v1p3 adlcp_v1p3.xsd
                              http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlseq_v1p3 adlseq_v1p3.xsd
                              http://www.adlnet.org/xsd/adlnav_v1p3 adlnav_v1p3.xsd
                              http://www.imsglobal.org/xsd/imsss imsss_v1p0.xsd">
<metadata>
<schema>ADL SCORM</schema>
<schemaversion>2004 3rd Edition</schemaversion>
</metadata>
<organizations default="golf_sample_default_org">
<organization identifier="golf_sample_default_org">
<title>Single SCO</title>
<item identifier="item_1" identifierref="resource_1">
    <title>Single SCO</title>
</item>
</organization>
</organizations>
<resources>
<resource identifier="resource_1" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormType="sco" href="index.html">
     <file href = "index.html"/>
     <file href = "SCORM_API_WRAPPER.js"/>
</resource>
</resources>
</manifest>
```

HTML page I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Single SCO</title>
<script src="SCORM_API_wrapper.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadPage() {
        pipwerks.SCORM.init();
        pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.completion_status", "completed");
        pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.success_status", "failed");
        pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.score.raw", "50");
        pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.score.min", "0");
        pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.score.max", "100");
        pipwerks.SCORM.save();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="loadPage()">
</body>
</html>
```

UPD: I modified html page to automatically make these calls.

Comment: Which LMS are you using? I know in Moodle, for example, you can configure it to look for particular statuses. Maybe your LMS considers failed attempts as "incomplete"?

Comment: I use WebTutor. Would this configuration work in Moodle?

Comment: I suggest adding the JavaScript code to your HTML page instead of using the JS console. This way you can be sure the right calls are made in the correct order, every time, and we will be able to see the actual JS code you're invoking. What you posted above is not the whole picture, and without seeing the code we have no way to know for sure what you're doing. It could be as simple as a typo somewhere.

Comment: I modified html page to automatically make these calls.

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but SCORM_API_WRAPPER.js is pipwerks SCORM Wrapper for JavaScript v1.1.20121005.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebTutor. I suggest testing with SCORM Cloud so that you can pin down if the problem is with your package or with WebTutor.

Comment: You may want to check if your getting a true/false off the ```var success = pipwerks.SCORM.init();```.  To also aid in debugging I have a bookmarklet that may show status when you launch the SCO.  I don't remember is the save() call terminates.  https://cybercussion.com/bookmarklets/SCORM/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're forgetting to set the exit status so you can re-load the same data -

`pipwerks.SCORM.set("cmi.exit", "suspend");`

Without the suspend state the next time you load it'll treat it as a new attempt, so the previous state won't get supplied to the API.